# How to undo sn.exe -Vr *

Tags: validation, strongname, sn.exe

I needed to debug EntityFramework to figure out why it didn't accept my connectionstring. And in order to do that I had to use the sn.exe -Vr * command since disabling one or two assemblies didn't work.

So now I want to restore everything to default, the problem was found, but now I don't have any strong name validation on my computer at all.

So how do I revert strong name validation to the default setting using the sn command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"sn.exe -Vu *" is the opposite of "sn.exe -Vr *". See "sn.exe -?".